# Google Maps offline cacheing (android app development)

Tags: android, google-maps, caching

**INTRO**

i have done a lots and lots of googling and also search every question (literally) in stack overflow about google maps offline cacheing in android.

every answer is either not clear or its redirecting me to some google maps terms and services . and says that the offline storage of bulk google maps data is not allowed .

but my requirement is different and i am helpless.

**REQUIREMENT**

i have created an ***android app*** to show location and show the roots to different location and keep the track of user if he/she is in an unknown place and lost their way.
so i want to save the maps tiles of that particular area when the user confirms to save the data. the data will be later used to track in offline mode.
i want to save data of a ***locality(small area)*** and thats for some ***limited time***. i don't want to use **OSMDroid** as it is not my requirement.

**MY STUDIES TILL NOW**

and what i have studied about google maps , it allows for my requirement. but i do not get a clue how to do it. google maps allows for **temporary cacheing of tiles for small area for a limited time**.(please correct me if i am wrong.)

[link of google maps T&C](https://www.google.com/work/earthmaps/legal/us/maps_purchase_agreement.html) 
(this link has told about cacheing on 4.4 and i don't think i violate any of this terms.)

please help me. i am stuck in the middle of the project.
any full example will be greatly appreciated.

thank you

Comment: have you tried this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-infowindow and this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/save-widget

Comment: the link you suggested is for java script. how to do it in android. beside that i  don't think this is the thing i want. (please correct me if i am wrong).

Comment: you can use java script in android why you can't ?

Comment: yes i can . can you please suggest me an example .

Comment: hey i checked the link and studied . this is not what i require.

Comment: this just save a place in google maps and show you later as star mark and remind you . i want to save the tiles into device memory and load them into the map when the internet is not connected to provide the tile data in need.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7567/solution-for-android-map-app-with-offline-use may be you found your answer here

Comment: why do i get -1 in my question ?

Comment: do any one have tried this . any one have a demo solution that they can share. i am not even getting a clue. is this thing possible without OSMDroid .? and please be specific . do not suggest some random post which do not do what i want. i have specifically mentioned what i need. its clear . for ANDROID. for OFFLINE. for GOOLE MAPs .

Comment: Sagar, have you found any solution for this ?  i am trying over week but unable to get that work ? kindly let me know

Comment: nope @HeshanSandeepa . i am still trying. as google officially do not allow this . so there is not good solution to this . you can use osmdroid if you want .

Comment: @SagarNayak , thank you for the response , really appreciate. Yes, i will start look for an another option.